# PyCharm : Configuring Python Console

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm

I am running Conda environments on a Ubuntu VM box (that has no display). I am trying to use PyCharm but the PyCharm Python Console won't import libraries correctly for some reason. E.g. `import pandas` gives:

> ```
> Backend Qt5Agg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
> QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display  bash: line 1: 12547
> Aborted                 (core dumped) env "PYTHONUNBUFFERED"="1"
>  "PYTHONPATH"="/home/local/US/me/max:/home/local/US/me/.pycharm_helpers/pydev"
>  "PYCHARM_HOSTED"="1" "IPYTHONENABLE"="True"
>  "PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE"="1" "JETBRAINS_REMOTE_RUN"="1"
>  "PYTHONIOENCODING"="UTF-8"
>
> /home/local/US/me/conda/envs/research/bin/python2.7
> /home/local/US/me/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py 0 0 Process
> finished with exit code 134
> ```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling `pandas`, `conda`, and everything and nothing fixes this. Also, when I run Python or IPython from the terminal in PyCharm, then everything works perfectly. I can import all packages as needed with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you don't select correct python interpreter. select correct in settings like [image: this]

also look at this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html

In addition yo cat use `-X`(big x) in ssh for X forwarding

Comment: I am pretty sure the interpreter is correct because I can run my codee (and libraries without errors), how can i add the -X when PyCharm ssh in the VM for me?